# how obtain the variance from a Taylor's series

Tags: statistics

I have the following approximation:

$$f(x) \simeq f(a) + f^{'}(a)(x - a)$$

Letting $a = \mu_{x}$, the mean of $X$, a Taylor seties expansion of $y=f(x)$ about $\mu_{x}$ gives the approximation:
$$y=f(x) \simeq f(\mu_{x})  +f^{'}(\mu_{x})(x - \mu_{x})$$
Taking the variance of both sides yields:

$$Var(Y) = Var(f(X)) \simeq [f^{'}(\mu_{x})]^2 Var(X)$$

I am trying to understand how they obtained the variance of $f(\mu_{x})  +f^{'}(\mu_{x})(x - \mu_{x})$, I have been studying the properties of the variance but for me is not clear.

I appreciate any help

Comment: Are you asking why the variance of $f(\mu)  +f'(\mu)(X - \mu)$ is $f'(\mu)^2$ times the variance of $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
Var(c + Y) = var(Y)
$$
for a constant c (like $c = f(\mu_x)$).

$$
Var(cY) = c^2 Var(Y)
$$
from the definition. Apply this to the second term to pull out the $(f'(\mu))^2$.

Then once more observe that $Var(X - c) = Var(X)$ to get rid of the $\mu_x$ in the remaining parenthesized term.

By the way, the whole analysis is nonsense unless the Taylor series actually converges to $f$; as an example, consider the variance of $f(X)$ where $X$ is, say, uniform on $[-1, 1]$ and 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-x^{-2}} & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases}.
$$
The Taylor series for this function is the zero polynomial, but you wouldn't want to claim that $f(X)$ had no variance. :(

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}Var(Y)= Var[f(X)]&\simeq Var[f(\mu_x)+f'(\mu_x)(X-\mu_x)]\\&= Var(X-\mu_x)[f'(\mu_x)]^2\\
&=Var(X)[f'(\mu_x)]^2\end{align}
where we have used the following property of the variance:
$$Var(aX+b)=a^2Var(X)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let X be a random variable with variance $Var(X)$ and let $a,b$ be two scalers, it then holds that $Var(aX + b) = a^{2}Var(X)$.

Apply this to $f(\mu_{x}) + f'(\mu_{x})(x-\mu_{x})$ to get the desired result.

An important thing to note is that $f(\mu_{x}),f'(\mu_{x}),\mu_{x} $ are all constants.